# Lightning component won't compile because of false dependency report

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I originally had two design parameters and their corresponding attributes in my component. Afterwards, I deleted both the parameters and attributes, but, after doing so, I couldn't compile my code because my component 'depends' on my design attributes and vise-versa.

design attribute error message:

```
'You can't remove design attributes 'SearchString,isValid' when the component implements a Lightning Page interface.:'
```

component error message:

```
'No ATTRIBUTE named SearchString found: Source'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing these interfaces (temporarily) from your component / app markup:

- flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes
- flexipage:availableForRecordHome
- forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes
- force:appHostable

These are the `Lightning Page interfaces` that your error message is talking about. If you remove them, then they can't be hosted in the App Builder and so won't need the dependency to the .design file.

Comment: Nice call. Took me forever to find this and remove all of my  boguys attributes @todo remove once the craziness is fixed by SFDC :)